# Configure MongoDB in Spring Boot using environment variables

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and am trying to configure a connection to MongoDB using environment variables - i.e. I have followed an example online showing how to configure my mongo database/host/port via application.properties, but I want my configuration to come from environment variables - what is the best approach to do this?
Thanks

Comment: You can specify the mongodb properties under your application.properties and use spring provided MongoTemplate to establish the connection and access
 An Example :
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/test
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true

Comment: I have managed this using an example online, but I was wondering what the best approach was using environment variables, rather than specifying the values in the application.properties file

Comment: Hi - Sorry, as someone new to stack overflow, why has the question been given a -1? Is there something wrong with the question? Just wondering ...

Answer (score 12):

After some digging, I've managed to get it working by using an application.properties file, but specifying the env variable names within the file, e.g.

```
spring.data.mongodb.database = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.host = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST}
spring.data.mongodb.port = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT}
```

Comment: I think it is the same thing I had mentioned in my comment, you are using 3 different variables whereas I have mentioned all this under one variable

Comment: Sorry, your values were hard coded, I was looking to inject the values via environment variables, unless I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a fallback-value if necessary

```
spring.data.mongodb.host = ${SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST:localhost}
```